# multiple pie chart dimentions error in python

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have the dictionary in python:

```
dict = {1: {'A': 11472, 'C': 8405, 'T': 11428, 'G': 6613}, 2: {'A': 11678, 'C': 9388, 'T': 10262, 'G': 6590}, 3: {'A': 2945, 'C': 25843, 'T': 6980, 'G': 2150}, 4: {'A': 1149, 'C': 24552, 'T': 7000, 'G': 5217}, 5: {'A': 27373, 'C': 3166, 'T': 4494, 'G': 2885}, 6: {'A': 19300, 'C': 4252, 'T': 7510, 'G': 6856}, 7: {'A': 17744, 'C': 5390, 'T': 7472, 'G': 7312}}
```

this dictionary has 7 sub-dictionaries and every sub-dictionary has 4 items. I am trying to make 7 pie charts in the same figure (multiple plot) and every pit chart would have 4 sections. to plot the data I am using the following function.

```
def plot(array):
    array = np.array([list(val.values()) for val in dict.values()])
    df = pd.DataFrame(array, index=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], columns=['x', 'y','z','w', 'd', 't', 'u'])
    plt.style.use('ggplot')
    colors = plt.rcParams['axes.color_cycle']
    fig, axes = plt.subplots(1,4, figsize=(10,5))
    for ax, col in zip(axes, df.columns):
        ax.pie(df[col], labels=df.index, autopct='%.2f', colors=colors)
        ax.set(ylabel='', title=col, aspect='equal')
    axes[0].legend(bbox_to_anchor=(0, 0.5))
    fig.savefig('plot.pdf')
    plt.show()
```

but this function returns a figure with 4 pie charts and every pie chart has 7 sections. and if I replace "index" and "columns" I will get the following `error`:

```
ValueError: Shape of passed values is (4, 7), indices imply (7, 4)
```

do you know how I can fix it? here is the figure that I will get BUT is NOT correct.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

There are two issues:

- You want 7 subplots but you were only creating 4 using `plt.subplots(1,4)`. You should define `(1,7)` to have 7 subfigures.
- You need to reshape your data accordingly. Since you need 7 pie charts, each with 4 entries, you need to reshape your array to have a shape of `(4, 7)`

P.S: I am using `matplotlib 2.2.2` where `'axes.color_cycle'` is depreciated.

Below is your modified `plot` function.

---

```
def plot():
    array = np.array([list(val.values()) for val in dict.values()]).reshape((4, 7))
    df = pd.DataFrame(array, index=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], columns=['x', 'y','z','w', 'd', 't', 'u'])
    plt.style.use('ggplot')
    colors = plt.rcParams['axes.color_cycle']
    fig, axes = plt.subplots(1,7, figsize=(12,8))
    for ax, col in zip(axes, df.columns):
        ax.pie(df[col], labels=df.index, autopct='%.2f', colors=colors)
        ax.set(ylabel='', title=col, aspect='equal')
    axes[0].legend(bbox_to_anchor=(0, 0.5))
```

[image]